# Where I can test a speech grammer (GrXML) script?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am developing a speech grammer in [GrXML](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/) format to test the text returned by the speech engine.
I tried to use [Google Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/) but I found out that it does not support user provided speech grammer(correct me if I am wrong). 
I want know that how can I test my GrXML script (online or offline) if possible free of cost (just for testing purpose) and how can I use it with python.

Speech Grammer I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<grammar xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" mode="voice" root="main">

    <rule id="main" scope="public">

        <item repeat="1-16">
            <ruleref uri="#digit">
                <tag>out.concept = out.concept + rules.digit;</tag>
            </ruleref>
        </item>
    </rule>

    <rule id="digit">
        <one-of>
            <item>0</item>
            <item>1</item>
            <item>2</item>
            <item>3</item>
            <item>4</item>
            <item>5</item>
            <item>6</item>
            <item>7</item>
            <item>8</item>
            <item>9</item>
        </one-of>
    </rule>
</grammar>
```

Comment: Did you find any way to test GrXML?

Comment: https://evolution.voxeo.com/ I tried this site online services.